# How to manage backlog preparation during current sprint

Tags: scrum, sprint, product-backlog

In my team, the Business Analysis is also a scrum team member. He will prepare all user stories to the Product backlog, but his tasks also should be managed with timeline/estimation.

Should we put those preparation tasks into the Sprint backlog together with development stories, or should we have a different way of tracking them?

Comment: What is a "sprint for preparation"?

Comment: There may be a couple different answers. To give you the best one, what is the BA doing to prepare the backlog items?

Comment: @CandiedOrange: That means preparing user stories, requirements for next sprints

Comment: Why would you not point it like you would anything else? Pre Grooming a backlog is not a static task and can vary depending on the complexity of the backlog. It should be tracked as part of the Sprint as it impacts the ability to complete that Sprint.

Answer (score 2):

I  my experience meetings don't really fit into sprints and BA work tends to be lots of meetings.

I would not try and squeeze this type of work into scrum, which works well for dev teams with well defined tasks, but not for things which rely on people or things outside of the team.

If you must, have them turn up at the standup and report what's going on, but don't bother with estimating their tasks or putting them in the sprint. It will only throw off your velocity estimates.

The BA is preparing the stories for the dev team and thus will be working at a different cadence than them. Not participating in the sprint goal, but getting things ready for future sprints

Answer (score 1):

You should do whatever works best for your team. This is a problem for your scrum team to solve during its retrospectives.

If it helps you to create a "groom backlog" story, and to estimate the time spent doing that task, then there's nothing wrong with doing that if it helps with your estimation. This is not normally how scrum teams work, but it sounds like it's normal for *your* scrum team.

OTOH, if it doesn't help, there's no point in doing it. Instead, simply assume that that member won't be contributing as many hours to the sprint as the rest of team. Treat the time they spend on backlog grooming no different than time they spend on vacation, or taking a training class, or doing any other non-sprint activity.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some [ScrumBut](https://www.scrum.org/resources/what-scrumbut) is occurring.  Please read [The Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html).

> Business Analysis is also a scrum team member

GREAT!  `Cross-functional teams have all competencies needed to accomplish the work without depending on others not part of the team.`  Note that `The Scrum Team consists of a Product Owner, the Development Team, and a Scrum Master` so the BA could be a member of the Development Team<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> or the Product Owner but cannot be a separate role.

> he [Business Analyst] will prepare all user stories as backlog of next sprints

Product Backlog items are forecast for each Sprint by the Development Team during the Sprint Planning event.  If the BA is scheduling work, then it is traditional, plan-driven project management and not Scrum.

Scrum is a framework; therefore it permits any processes, tools, skills, techniques to be used within it.<sup><sup>2</sup></sup>  Scrum also requires self-organization.  Discuss to determine how to work effectively and efficiently together.

---

<sup>1 `Scrum recognizes no sub-teams in the Development Team, regardless of domains that need to be addressed like testing, architecture, operations, or business analysis;`</sup>

<sup>2 As long as those practices and approaches do not violate the `roles, events, artifacts, and the rules that bind them together`.</sup>